# Potential negative slack in maximum weighted bipartite matching

Tags: graph-theory, mathematical-optimization

I'm reading [Galil's paper on "Efficient Algorithms for Finding Maximum Matching in Graphs"](https://www.cs.kent.edu/%7Edragan/GraphAn/p23-galil.pdf).

Suppose *u* is adjacent to *v*, *v* is adjacent to *w*, *w* is adjacent to *x*, *v* and *w* are currently matched, *x* is matched but to none of *u*, *v* or *w*. Although this subgraph is bipartite, I'd like to ask about the blossom algorithm for general, weighted graphs.

Can the slacks for (*u*, *v*), (*v*, *w*), and (*w*, *x*) all be zero, *u* and *w* have the same label, the search for an augmenting path fail, causing the dual variable for *w* to be decreased (making the slack for (*w*, *x*) negative)?